# Show that $\sqrt{1+x} < 1+\frac{x}{2}$ if $x>0$

Tags: calculus

I feel like this is gonna involve the mean value theorem and the intermediate value theorem. I've worked problems like this given a specific interval, but this is talking about all positive numbers. Not sure where to start.

Comment: Draw a picture. Find the tangent to the right hand side at $x=0$.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just square both sides?
$$ 1+x < 1+x+\frac{x^2}{4} $$
is trivial.

Comment: Wow. Too easy. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

We have that for all $x>0$, we have
$$
1+x<1+x+\frac{x^2}{4}=\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2,
$$
and hence
$$
\sqrt{1+x}<1+\frac{x}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

From the Bernoulli's inequality: $$(1+x)^r\le1+rx$$ for $0<x<1$

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your inequality in the form $(1+x/2)^2-(1+x)=1+x^2/4+x-1-x=x^2/4>0$ which is true.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to know convex properties. 
$$
x\to 1 + \frac12x
$$is the equation of the tangent line of the strict concave function $x\to\sqrt{1+x}$ at the point $x=0$. Hence the result is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Apply AM-GM inequality for $$1+x \,\,\,\,\text{and} \,\,\,\,\,1.$$ Since $x>0$ strickly inequality holds.